# ios manipulating a views elements programmatically

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to change the hidden property to some of my elements programmatically based on button click.  In javascript I would do document.getElementById('element').display = 'block'.  Is there a way of doing this is iOS something like: self.'element'.hidden = NO;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIView** has a boolean property called **hidden**, which is **NO** by default, you can set it to **YES** to hide your view. To retrieve views, is it possible to assign tags, which are merely integers (default 0):

```
[myView setTag:10];
```

so..

```
[[myParentView viewWithTag:10] setHidden:YES];
```

This is pretty similar to js, otherwise you can iterate over subviews:

```
NSArray *viewsArray = [parentView subviews];

for (UIView *view in viewsArray) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any UIView subclass (e.g. UIButton, UILabel etc.) has a 'hidden' property. Set this to YES of NO to show and hide the view. e.g.

```
myButton.hidden = NO;
myLabel.hidden = YES;
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW61).